# Extract select match value of same contents in XML file

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

I using this command for below xml file.

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//channel[protected = "True"]/playlist_url' -nl file.xml
```

and result;

```
host.net/aa/vodpr
host.net/aa/vodpr/con_tv_r.php
```

Can I choose a line in result? Example only last line or 2. line?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<items>   

<channel>
<title><![CDATA[*** variable text ***]]></title>
<playlist_url><![CDATA[http://host.net/aa/15_info/]]></playlist_url>
</channel>

<channel>       
<title><![CDATA[*** variable text ***]]></title>
<playlist_url><![CDATA[http://host.net/aa/16_info/]]></playlist_url>
</channel>

<channel>      
<title><![CDATA[*** variable text ***]]></title>
<playlist_url><![CDATA[http://host.net/aa/vodpr/]]></playlist_url>  
<protected>True</protected> 
</channel>

<channel>
<title><![CDATA[*** variable text ***]]></title>
<playlist_url><![CDATA[http://host.net/aa/vodpr/con_tv_r.php]]></playlist_url>
<protected>True</protected> 
</channel>

</items>
```

Answer (score 1):

To select the `playlist_url` value from the `channel` node by position in the list, use `position()` and compare with some positive integer:

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//channel[position() = 4]/playlist_url' -nl file.xml
http://host.net/aa/vodpr/con_tv_r.php
```

(in this case, you could use just `[4]` in place of `[position() = 4]`).

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//channel[position() > 2]/playlist_url' -nl file.xml
http://host.net/aa/vodpr/
http://host.net/aa/vodpr/con_tv_r.php
```

To get the last two from a list of unknown length, combine the test with `last()`:

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//channel[position() >= last() - 1]/playlist_url' -nl file.xml
http://host.net/aa/vodpr/
http://host.net/aa/vodpr/con_tv_r.php
```

To get the second "protected" URL:

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//channel[protected = "True"][2]/playlist_url' -nl file.xml
http://host.net/aa/vodpr/con_tv_r.php
```